# How to implement my own custom advertisement in my own android application using predefiend SDK's for ad (like admob etc)

Tags: android, admob, adsense, revmob

I am working on advertisement integration for my android application, the problem is that I'm having 3 applications live on android app store.

Therefore I want that my ad SDK will show ad of these 3 applications only in these application. Means 1st application will show ad of only 2 and 3 my application, no other ad, I want to use pre- defined SDK's available on internet (like admob, revmob etc).

Guys please help me regarding this...

Comment: Y don't u try making your own ads. AdMob is made for displaying ads by companies that pay Google, unless you pay google for advertisment, I don't think that will work. You can easily display adds though and just make them link to the page in google play

Comment: Thanks for you commment but how can i make my own ad? Using layout??

Answer (score 5):

> You can just make a layout to act as your banner ad and include it within your other layouts and then just add an onclick function to the banner.
>
> Or
>
> Use admob for my ads. Admob has "***in-house ads***" where you can run your ads with in your app for free. You can choose for them to display exclusively and use admob to track the statistics for which ads are being clicked and how often they are being displayed.
>
> http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1619751

Comment: Actually the link you provided is for old one, can u please provide me a new one as ad-mob's web page is changed.. And secondly i already tried this "in-house ads" but its not working as in new ad-mob. Apart fro this it also show's an error message to confirm the billing info first.. Please provide a proper procedure to do this.

Comment: Try his first suggestion

Comment: @Ronish can you please provide some code example to implement your first option?

Comment: Is the first suggestion allowed? I mean, will Google allow apps with custom ads using imageview to be uploaded on play store?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly using Admob SDK with something that they call [House Ads](https://developer.android.com/distribute/users/house-ads.html).

Answer (score 1):

If somebody stumbles up here, I've made up a library for this purpose...

Currently quite in an early stage but can be used in production.

Supports AdDialog, Interstitial & NativeAd format! :)

https://github.com/ItzNotABug/HouseAds

Comment: Good job. I want to use it without json file. Can I upload all required fields in firestore document? Is it possible? Please guide me

Comment: @Pooja Currently only json format is supported, if you have hosting constraints then you can use Firebase Hosting.. else if you need non-json support, you can fork the library and make your desired changes.